# How to use basic authentication in a HTTP liveness probe in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Docker container that expose a health check that is protected by a basic authentication. I've read the documentation on liveness probes [here](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/liveness/README.html) but I cannot find any details of how to specify basic auth credentials. Is this not supported by Kubernetes? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It is now possible to add headers for liveness probes:

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /healthz
    port: 8080
    httpHeaders:
      - name: Authorization
        value: Basic aGE6aGE=
```

It may be worth noting that:

> if the browser uses Aladdin as the username and OpenSesame as the
>   password, then the field's value is the base64-encoding of
>   Aladdin:OpenSesame, or QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l. Then the
>   Authorization header will appear as:
>
> Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

You can use the command `base64` in your shell to create this string:

```
echo -n "Aladdin:OpenSesame" | base64
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no direct support for an authenticated HTTP probe. If you cannot expose an unauthenticated health check (on a cluster internal IP), then I think your best bet is to use a probe with an [ExecAction](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/api-reference/definitions.html#_v1_execaction), and a command like:

```
curl -G --fail --silent --output=/dev/null -u ${AUTH_USER}:${AUTH_PASSWD} localhost:${AUTH_PORT}
```

Note that the command is executed inside the health-checked container, so you will need to do something slightly different if it's set up to bypass auth for localhost connections.